# Isekai manga where the king killed the demon king, but kept his head as a friend

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I remember this isekai manga that had a short side story where the king just went out and killed the demon king but kept his head to keep as a friend. If possible what is it?

Comment: You referred to this as an isekai, so was somebody transported to another world in this story? If so, was it the king, or another character?

Comment: Im pretty sure it was an isekai but I couldve been fantasy. It was the king that killed the demon lord.

Comment: Isekai typically involves someone from the real world being transported to a fantasy world. If the whole story takes place in a fantasy world, then it's not isekai, just fantasy. By the way, you said the king killing the demon lord was a "short side story"... so what was the _main_ story?

Answer (score 2):

This is [Benriya Saitou-san, Isekai ni Iku](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=151039), aka "Handyman Saitou In Another World". The main storyline concerns the titular Saitou, who entered a fantasy world from ours. Completely unrelated to this, in Chapter 11.5, a king posts an ad for a hero to slay the demon lord. No one shows up, so he just does it himself and brings back the demon lord's severed head. The head is still alive, and the king plays chess with his new "friend".

[image]

Comment: Should I include any images from this chapter? I've never been certain what the policy for that is. I consider cover images fine, but I don't think they'd be helpful here, since it's a side story.

Comment: I'm no copyright lawyer, but the general consensus is that it "should be okay as long as you don't overdo it". See [this meta discussion](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10085/98028), and/or [this one](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1850/98028) for a more technical (but then less easy to understand for us copyright laypeople) explanation. I'd say that for a story-id question based on a manga (which is by nature an image-oriented medium), it's perfectly acceptable and truly appreciated to have visual evidence.